# Native: tried calling Push.hasPermission, but the Push plugin is not installed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I'm building an app with push notification in ionic 3 . I referred different tutorials  for the same. I reffered this link,[Pushnotification](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59)

I dont get any build issue, everything works , But when I try on physical device I see on my console.

```
   03-22 17:56:28.062 32273 32273 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(47546)] "Native: tried calling Push.hasPermission, but the Push plugin is not installed.", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (47546)
03-22 17:56:28.062 32273 32273 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(47552)] "Install the Push plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push'", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (47552)
03-22 17:56:28.063 32273 32273 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(84647)] "Notification init start", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (84647)
03-22 17:56:28.066 32273 32273 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(47546)] "Native: tried calling PushNotification.init, but the PushNotification plugin is not installed.", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (47546)
03-22 17:56:28.071 32273 32273 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(84700)] "Notification init end", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (84700)
03-22 17:56:28.088 32273 32273 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1370)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (1370)
```

I dont see push plugin folder inside /**/appName/platforms/android/platform_www/plugins.
For other plugin like Camera,Map,geolocation etc there are folders.

I ran below command to install push plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support --save
 npm install --save @ionic-native/push
```

In package.json

```
"phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "senderId"
      }
```

In config.xml

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.2.2">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="seberID" />
    </plugin>
```

Edited

```
$ionic info

cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v7.10.0
    npm               : 4.2.0
    OS                : Linux 4.13

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /home/ullas/Android/Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: please provide ionic info for your project.

Comment: @paril Edited question

Answer (score 0):

Need to check version of plugin.

According to plugin version update version of your Cordova CLI, Cordova Android, Cordova iOS and Cocoapods.

You will get warning for same while adding platform for, what is the your plugin not installed.

Check installation requirements [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md#installation-requirements).

Comment: Thanks @paril I have checked this before , the plugin version which I am using is  2.2.2 and there is no information about this version .

Comment: you will get exact reason while adding platform why your plugin not get installed.

Comment: I got  warning 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.4.6
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.4.6
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.4.6
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@4.4.6
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@4.4.6
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.4.6
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@3.12.1
└── @ionic-native/push@4.6.0

npm WARN @ionic-native/push@4.6.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none was installed

Comment: what exact log/comment do you get while you remove platform and add it again for plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the cordova fcm plugin got some changes few days ago.

You just have to change the import statement.

New import: `import { FCM } from "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx";`

And in constructor: `constructor(private fcm: FCM, private platform: Platform){ }`

Make sure to call any method from fcm after the device is ready.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.fcm.getToken()
      .then(deviceId => {})
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

See https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated#with-ionic